# how to solve tkinter.tclError python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
from tkinter import Tk , Button , Entry , Label 
from PIL import ImageTk , Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Image viewer app.")

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\pramo\Desktop\CODING\Python-files\I Love Python.png"))
img_label = Label(root, Image = img)
img_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code it shows error

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Image"

please help

Comment: The option is `image`, not `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a path in Python, it is case-sensitive and requires the file extensions when opening a file, for example `.txt`, `.png`, etc.

You are most likely missing the file extension on the file you are trying to open. For example, the file:

```
I love python
```

is different from the file:

```
I love python.png
```

So, edit your path to include the right file extension. In this case, I am just going to use `.png` as an example:

```py
r"C:\Users\pramo\Desktop\CODING\Python-files\I Love Python.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image path should be :

- r"C:\Users\pramo\Desktop\CODING\Python-files\I Love Python.png" ( add .png or whatever extension of your image)
- Also change line

> img_label = Label(root, Image = img)

To

> img_label = Label(root, image = img) # image instead of Image

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you haven't specified the file extension of your picture.
Let's say that your picture is a png file or a jpeg file, the name of your file would be `I Love Python.png` or `I Love Python.jpg` respectively.
So finally your directory path (for png) should be:

```
C:\Users\pramo\Desktop\CODING\Python-files\I Love Python.png
```